# Spatial join by categories in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I am using QGIS 2.4.0 and I have a vector layer which contains a remoteness indicator which is broken up into 5 categories. I would like to turn this into a layer that has these 5 categories collapsed into 2. On the included map I would like to join the green areas together into one group and the yellow and red areas into another group.

[image]

In the attribute table included I would like to join together the categories in the RA_Name11 field.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this I would:

1. Add a new field, perhaps called Value and of type integer
2. Select your two green categories and calculate them to say Value = 1
3. Select your red and yellow categories and calculate them to say Value = 2
4. Dissolve on Value.